# Importing MySQL query into Microsoft Excel using Power Query

Tags: mysql, excel, powerquery

I'm trying to import a MySQL query into MS Excel using Power Query. I get a database connection error, although everything else is working fine (the query, in a different program, included). I assume this would be due to the fact that the code contains user-defined variables, as such:

```
    SET @c:=1
```

Apparently Power Query doesn't like that, because replacing all instances of this variable makes the code work.

I could replace this variable by its value, but that would cost me a lot of time and would not be very elegant. I found what seemed to be a solution [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-do-I-pass-parameters-to-my-SQL-statement/m-p/119671#M50561), but if I try to do something along the lines of that, I get asked for permissions I cannot give, as this might affect the database.

Does anyone have an idea about what I need to do? Any workarounds? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My general approach would be to rebuild the logic of the SQL script in Steps using the PQ UI.  E.g. the first FROM table becomes the first table/view you navigate to, JOIN becomes Merge Queries, WHERE clause becomes Filter steps, UNION becomes Append Queries, etc.

I've built a lot of amazingly complex Queries this way - one step at a time.  It is a very flexible tool and a useful skill once you get going.  After over 20 years of coding in SQL, I now use PQ as my SQL query tool of preference.  It has so many advantages over custom code and generally it does a good job of "folding" your steps into a generated SQL statement.

Power Query has it's own Parameters functionality - perhaps you can use that to replace the variables.  It depends on how your variables are being used.